# pow function in C fails to recognize variable

Tags: c, pow

I have a problem with pow function in c. The variable Qb will give wrong output - it gives 10000 instead of 177827.941004 resulting in final output of 2007 instead of 2009

Compile command is by.
    `gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -o test_pow02 test_pow02.c -lm`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int my_rating = 2000;
    int opponent_rating = 2100;
    int coeff = 15;
    int score = 1;
    int new_rating;

    double Qa = pow(10, my_rating / 400); // 100000
    double Qb = pow(10, opponent_rating / 400); // 177827.941004

    double Ea = Qa / (Qa + Qb); 

    new_rating = my_rating + ( (score - Ea) * coeff );

    printf("Qa is %g\n", Qa);
    printf("Qb is %g\n", Qb);
    printf("New Rating is %d\n", new_rating);

    return 0;
}
```

But if I hardcoded 2100/400 into 5.25, it will work correctly. I already have -lm at the end. How do I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int my_rating = 2000;
    //int opponent_rating = 2100;
    int coeff = 15;
    int score = 1;
    int new_rating;

    double Qa = pow(10, my_rating / 400); // 100000
    double Qb = pow(10, 5.25); // 177827.941004

    double Ea = Qa / (Qa + Qb); 

    new_rating = my_rating + ( (score - Ea) * coeff );

    printf("Qa is %g\n", Qa);
    printf("Qb is %g\n", Qb);
    printf("New Rating is %d\n", new_rating);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation `pow(10, opponent_rating / 400);` does not equal to `177827.941004`.

```
opponent_rating / 400 == 5
```

Operations involving two integers will produce an integer,
in this case the result `5.25` gets clipped to `5`

You should divide with a double to get a double result `opponent_rating / 400.0` that is used in the [pow](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) function.

Comment: I would drop the `f` suffix. `pow` is going to work with doubles anyway so there's no reason to drop to `float` precision.